# JSON output different from the output of format table

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to get process name and process memory usage through a PowerShell command:

```
Get-Process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName |
    Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={
        '{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)
    };a='right'} -AutoSize
```

But when I pipe it with `ConvertTo-Json` the output is different which gets me details of ClassID, outOfBand, which is not the output I expect.
I want the output in exact same way (Name and Mem (KB)) as it displays on screen but in JSON format.

Comment: Don't pipe `Format-Table` output to `ConvertTo-Json` - use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen But how do I calculate the Memory Size then? When I use Format-Table it calculates but using Select-Object it doesnt calculate the memory used by process

Comment: `Select-Object` accepts calculated properties just like `Format-Table`. Show the code that isn't working if you want qualified help :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks I figured it out :) and answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is by using `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`

```
Get-Process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName |
    Select-Object Name, @{n='Mem';
        e={(($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)}} |
    ConvertTo-Json
```